# Merge [drag] and [dragging]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

In my opinion [drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drag) and [dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dragging) are synonymous and should be joined, or [dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dragging) removed.

[drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drag): •Tag wiki ✔ •Questions tagged: 1,695 questions

> In computer graphical user interfaces, drag is the first phase of a drag-and-drop operation. This involves selecting a virtual object by "grabbing" it and dragging it with the mouse down to a different location or onto another virtual object. An instance of some object relating to what was grabbed is usually brought with the drag operation.

[dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dragging): •Questions tagged: 28 questions

Comment: Are these even necessary?

Comment: Couldn't they both be removed in favor of "drag-and-drop"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drag-and-drop

Comment: @Matsemann They're not actually the same thing. Drag AND Drop isn't the same thing. Maybe I'm dragging a window. There's no drop there.

Comment: Drag is especially relevant on touch devices (compared to drag-and-drop which is quite common in desktop)

Comment: Then the tag wiki should reflect the difference, as it is now it literally says it's the first part of a dragndrop operation.

Comment: The OP knows what the question is about. Also, often in IT jargon 'drag' is referred to define the action. Hence, dropping or joining 'dragging' with 'drag' makes sense.